# how to run a java file from a parent directory?

Tags: java, classpath

I am able to compile a java file that is inside a directory by using javac <directory_name>/Solution.java.
but I am not able to run the java program in the same manner ie. java /Solution.

as it gives me this error :

> Error: Could not find or load main class code.Solution Caused by:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Solution (wrong name: code/Solution)

*Here code is my directory name.*

I could cd into the directory and do it. which actually works but that is not the behavior that I desire.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Please run class with fully qualified class name. If your class is inside a folder then please add package in your class. Let's say your directory name is "mydirectory" then please add package declaration in your class "package mydirectory;". While executing, run file with fully qualified class name i.e. mydirectory.Solution

Comment: Read about the classpath and the `-classpath` option for the `java` command.

Comment: thank you pcsutar and @Stephen, both of your Solutions work. although with Stephen's Solution I was able to compile and run my java file without adding the package <directoryName> line. just leaving this out here for others.